# I get a command prompt instead of login screen when I boot ubuntu

Tags: installation, boot

Is that normal? I am currently (trying to) use 12.10.

Comment: I think your X is not loading for some reason. Posting a link to contents of /var/log/Xorg.0.log would help.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal if you installed the server version. Did you?

You can just install the graphical desktop on a server if you did:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Or are you seeing some error messages?